# What is Comet address of Compound III on Polygon mainnet

Tags: defi, compound-protocol

I want to supply & borrow from compound III on polygon mainnet. As per Compound III docs, I need to call the supply & withdraw method on Comet instance. Take a look [here](https://docs.compound.finance/collateral-and-borrowing/#supply). As per solidity example, I need to provide CometAddress to instalise the Comet instance. But I am not able to find it. What is the CometAddress for compound III?

Thanks.